# Order col-x with Bootstrap, one above the other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with Bootstrap.
I have a 3-columns page where each content has a different size, so here the result I have :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F43qV.jpg

Here's the problem : Do you see where is the Column 4 ? I want the "new" line begin at the first place.
I tried a .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n+1) but it clearing, and I don't want that. I want one above the other, and in the good order. Like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QIM6.jpg

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div>
    column1
  </div>
  <div>
    column4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div>
    column2
  </div>
  <div>
    column5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div>
    column3
  </div>
</div>
```

Not very nice solution but it can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block; for the class col-lg-4
and remove the white space between the columns`<!-- -->`.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
column1
</div><!--
--><div class="col-lg-4">
column2
</div>
```